# Should I upgrade my computer?

Tags: memory, ssd, processor

I hope that I can get a solution for my issue.

I have two computers:

One is an [AsusN56VJ](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sFbt88As1pg) laptop, a little bit old:

The configuration is:

- i5 323M (2 physical cores with 4 threads) 2.6 GHz.
- 6 GB of RAM at 1067 MHz (1*4GB and 1*2GB)
- 500 GB of HDD
- NVidia Geforce 635m (VRAM: 2 GB)

My second computer is a PackardBell desktop:

- E5700 (2 cores, 3 GHz)
- 4 GB of RAM
- 120 GB SSD
- HD 6750 graphical card (2 GB).

So what I want is to buy a new computer, but I hesitate between a laptop and a desktop because I have those two computers.

What should I do? Because I want a computer which can run 2016 games and do some programming stuff, I see that I can't upgrade my desktop on the contrary of my laptop where I can upgrade to 32 of RAM at 1600 MHz and a new SSD.

I'm asking if it is a wise choice to upgrade a my laptop to 16 GB of RAM knowing that I have a processor with only 2 physical cores.

If you were in my place, what would you do? I have between 800 and 1000 dollar.

Comment: I would go with a desktop. If you were to buy a desktop, would you want it pre-built or would you be fine with building a parts list?

Comment: no i would build mijn desktop , but what about the laptop , can i upgrade it efficiently ?

Comment: Does "mijn" == "my own", sorry I am a bit confused.

Comment: sorry i speak a little bit nederaland , so sometimes i use nederlands word , i would say my own.

Comment: No problem, just wanted to verify.

Comment: So are your dollars Netherlands dollars? or US dollars? And what games do you plan on playing, what programming compliers/interpreters/IDEs do you plan on using? What sized projects and what expected performance? If it's an 800 US dollars budget, I'd be looking at a completely rebuilt desktop, maybe reusing the SSD, which should be good for 1080p gaming these days, and be reasonably fast for programming (depends what language, I guess) You might even have enough left to get a bigger SSD or a new monitor as an extra.

Comment: There is one major issue with this question:  It is opinion based.  It asks "should I" upgrade.  This will lead to opinion based answers.  What it should do is list what the possible upgrade options are, and ask which are the better options to take for *insert application here*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go with a desktop build [like this](https://pcpartpicker.com/list/G3YgCy).

It is on a Z170a chipset, which will allow you to overclock *if you decide to upgrade to a K series skylake or kabylake CPU*. The cooler should accommodate a reasonable overclock.

With the z170a SLI plus, you can use 2 way SLI or 3 way crossfire if you have compatible GPUs. The GTX 1060 should easily tackle most 2016 games.

2 drives: a SSD for boot and for software that you need to access quickly (like games) and a 1TB HDD for storing files.

***Specs/Parts are as follows:***

-**CPU**: Intel Core i3-6100 3.7GHz **($118.98 @ Amazon)**

-**CPU Coole**r: Cooler Master Hyper 212 EVO **($34.99 @ Amazon)**

-**Motherboard**: MSI Z170A SLI PLUS ($135.95 @ Amazon)

-**Memory**: Corsair Vengeance 8GB (2 x 4GB) DDR4-2133 **($49.99 @ Amazon)**

-**Storage**: Samsung 850 EVO-Series 250GB 2.5" SSD  **($89.99 @ Amazon)**

-**Storage**: Western Digital Caviar Blue 1TB 3.5" **($49.99 @ Amazon)**

-**Video Card**: EVGA GeForce GTX 1050 2GB **($116.99 @ Amazon)**

-**Power Supply**: EVGA 500W 80+ Certified ATX Power Supply  **($37.99 @ Amazon)**

-**Operating System**: Microsoft Windows 10 Home OEM 64-bit  **($90.72 @ Amazon)**

-**Case**: Thermaltake Versa H22 **($43.46 @ Amazon)**

### Total: $769.05 (for the PC build, $859.05 with additional laptop RAM)

--

You *can* upgrade your laptop from 6GB to 16GB of RAM, but I would only do this if I needed the extra RAM. Having extra RAM isn't going to make a difference in performance you aren't said extra RAM.

> I'm asking if it is a wise choice to upgrade a my laptop to 16 GB of RAM knowing that I have a processor with only 2 physical cores.

In response to that, core count doesn't necessarily mean you can't use more RAM. You should be able to utilize as much RAM as the manufacturer says is supported.[The i5 3230M supports up to 32GB of RAM](http://ark.intel.com/products/72164/Intel-Core-i5-3230M-Processor-3M-Cache-up-to-3_20-GHz-rPGA), but I believe this is limited to 16GB in your laptop (due to chipset limitations?). Furthermore, your laptop's i5 3230M is dual core and hyperthreaded. [Basically, it's like having four cores.](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/architecture-and-technology/hyper-threading/hyper-threading-technology.html)

--

If you feel like you need more RAM for your laptop take a look at something like this:

[- Timetec® (P/N 76TT13NUS2R8-8G) Dual Rank 1333MHz DDR3 (PC3-10600) Non-ECC Unbuffered CL9 204 Pin SODIMM 2Rx8 512x8 1.5V Windows PC Laptop Notebook RAM Memory Module Upgrade (16GB (2x8GB)) **($80 @ Amazon)**](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0145WDNF2)

--

N.B.: I have ommitted shipping charges, since I'm not sure where you need the parts to be shipped (internationally, locally etc...) (also depends on where you order the parts)